# SQL Server: Create Table for XML Import; Making Primary Key with Concatenated Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am creating a table to house my XML data that is coming in to my SQL Server database. Below is my code for my Create Table statement. My issue is I want to create a primary key that is a combination of two columns (SpecNum and IssueNum). A record should look like this (50125-001). However I am having issue with type mismatches and it will not allow my to declare it as xml. Does anyone know how to correct this? Please see code below and thank you in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE ImportXML (
    SpecNum xml,
    IssueNum xml,
    SpecStatus xml,
    ID as (SpecNum + '-' + IssueNum) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Comment: Can you use Index instead of Primary Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`50125-001` isn't XML, it's a `varchar`. I *suspect* what you want is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ImportXML (SpecNum int NOT NULL,
                            IssueNum int NOT NULL,
                            SpecStatus xml,
                            ID AS (CONVERT(varchar(10), SpecNum) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar(10), IssueNum))
                                PERSISTED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY); --You should really define the name of the PK CONSTRAINT too
```

Comment: Hi @Larnu, this is perfect. Yes in this case it is varchar I was unsure of how to sneak that in there in this case. Thanks again!